# Any Fast object detection method for Binary image?

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning

My current task is detecting abnormal spot from the binary image.

I trained simple Convolutional NN model for classifying abnormality for 1 spot.

I need to detect abnormal point from large image.

It requires thousands of classifying to inspect whole pixel. (I'm using this method, But It requires tremendous time.)

The example of large image is below.

*need to inspect white/Black patterns. (It seems hard to be segmented)

*yellow box is size of 1 patch of CNN

*the center of yellow box is the location of abnormal spot.

[Example of Large Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75D5v.jpg)

Comment: What is an "abnormal spot"? Do you have an image labeled as "good" and an image labeled as "defective"?

Comment: Yes. I have the dataset. there are good and detective. But the defective image's abnormal spot is inside the center(yellow box's center). and general input patch size will be similar to the size of yellow box. So I need to scan the image. But conservative scan method requires lots of computation

Comment: I am sorry but I still do not understand what is the defect. Can't upload an image of it?

Comment: What I meant is sliding window approach. (similar to find human faces from a  big image). But this is too slow for my application. It requires  about 6400 count of inferences to inspect whole grid of example image (400x400 pixel image is  inspected 80X80 with sub-inspecting) It costs 3seconds per 1image inspection.